# To pull instagram photo to website

Tags: jquery, instagram

I learned this from a forum but it didnt work for me. The photo didnt show up only the header.

Anyone can help me in this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-instagram/0.2.2/jquery.instagram.min.js"></script>
<title>Instagram Demo</title>

</head>

<body>

<h1>jQuery Instagram demo</h1>

<div class="instagram"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".instagram").instagram({
        userId: '0ce2a8c0d92248cab8d2a9d024f7f3ca',
        accessToken: '34834147.0ce2a8c.92d5a4d1d326438fb063a31b63e208a2',
        image_size: 'standard_resolution',
    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Error/Console Message..? Importing the proper instagram.js file..? More details.

Comment: there is no error message, when i run it in browser, only the header appear in my browser but dont have any picture, it should be pull some photo from instagram not only show the header.

Comment: @jovine Give link to the post where you learned from

Comment: this is the link http://jelled.com/instagram-gallery-tutorial/

Comment: So did you import the jquery.instagram.min.js file?

Comment: ya i think i have, this one right? <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: No... do you see the word instagram anywhere in that URL?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I see it now you did import it. Sorry~

Comment: @RUJordan anything went wrong with my code??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instafeed.js is a dead-simple way to add Instagram photos to your website. No jQuery required, just plain 'ol javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

Check this link **[INSTAFEED](http://instafeedjs.com/)**

Made a [**Insta demo**](http://jsbin.com/oxetok/16/edit) for you

Comment: ya i test this before but it still fail. I changded my code into this:
<h1>jQuery Instagram demo</h1>

<div id="instafeed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: '0ce2a8c0d92248cab8d2a9d024f7f3ca'
    });
    feed.run();

but it still dont pull any photo.

Comment: will it possible anything went wrong when i register the client?

Comment: https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=afd15cca7d664a1c964d54bac0488b93  try this

Comment: sorry i dont understand what is this? you mean to ask me to try on the user is?? sorry if i am wrong I am too new in this.

Comment: Updated my answer with demo @jovine ..Take a look at it

Comment: I had save wht i saw with ur link in my question.. I print screen it

Comment: Yeah tats fine json response ..anyways just go through my DEMO link in my answer

Comment: Lovely - works for me right away with full demo <3 Thank you @Vaibs_Cool

Answer (score 3):

You can get images by plain Jquery without any other plugin. as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var apiurl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<YOURUSERNAME>/media/recent/?access_token=<YOURACCESSTOKEN>&count=5&callback=?";
        $.getJSON(apiurl, function (data) {
            console.log("suatroot");
            var suatroot = data.data;

            console.log(suatroot);
            $.each(suatroot, function (key, val) {
                console.log("item");
                var itemobj = val.images.low_resolution.url;
                var hrefobj = val.link;
                var captobj = val.caption.text;
                console.log(captobj);
                console.log(itemobj);
                var suatpaket = "<a target='_blank' href='"+hrefobj+"'><img src='" + itemobj + "'/><br>"+captobj+"<br></a>";
                $(".instagram").append(suatpaket);
            });

        });
    });
```

and HTML:

```
<div class='instagram'></div>
```

By this solution your access token can be seen from source code of page, however, that is may be no big issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that hasn't any dependencies. Nor does it require an access token. For this snippet to work, you need to get a [bitsalad.co](http://www.bitsalad.co) URL for your feed.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='instagram-feed'></div>

<script>
(function(a,b,c,d){
  var $ = b.getElementById('instagram-feed');
  a['_i'] = function(d){
    d.forEach(function(i, x){
      html = "<img src='"+i.images.standard_resolution.url+"' />";
      $.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    })
  };
  var e = b.createElement(c);
  e.src = d;
  e.async=1;
  var f = b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];
  f.parentNode.insertBefore(e,f);
}(window, document, 'script','http://api.bitsalad.co/v1/feeds/<YOUR FEED ID HERE>?callback=_i'))
</script>

</body>
</html>
```